# How can I revoke my original AWS access key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'd like to revoke the access key and associated secret that Amazon originally set up for me when I created an AWS account. Their docs have a section [Deleting Access Keys from the Root User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html#id_root-user_manage_delete-key) , but that described clicking a "Delete" button in the list of Access Keys in IAM.

However, no access keys were listed for me. I tried to create a new one to see if that would override the old one, but the old one still works. IAM now only lists the new one and thus only allows me to delete that one.

How do I delete the original one?

Comment: AWS doesn't setup a key/secret when you create an account. Are you sure you are not confusing the IAM user with root user?

Comment: That was it, and I feel incredibly stupid now. If you convert your comment to an answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS doesn't setup a key/secret when you create an account.

It is possible you are confusing the IAM user with root user.